# Data class contsructor parameter default Composable value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, data-class

Is this possible to have data class that has constructor parameter which default value is set to some `@Composable val`? Something like this:

```kotlin
data class MyStyle(
    val marginTop: Dp = 8.dp,
    val marginBottom: Dp = 16.dp,
    val myTextStyle: TextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
)
```

Error:

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not allowed. If try to add `@Composable` to any constructor, you'll get this:

> This annotation is not applicable to target 'constructor'

This is because recomposition can happen many times during the view life cycle, down to a single frame during animation, in which case creating new objects for each recomposition can degrade the performance of your application. Check out more about recomposition in [Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model).

Instead you should use [`remember`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary?hl=vi#remember(kotlin.Function0)) to store the value between recompositions. You can pass all variables which may change as keys to `remember`, so the value will be recalculated only when needed:

```
@Composable
fun rememberMyStyle(
    marginTop: Dp = 8.dp,
    marginBottom: Dp = 16.dp,
    myTextStyle: TextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
) = remember(marginTop, marginBottom, myTextStyle) {
    MyStyle(marginTop, marginBottom, myTextStyle)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question a little by adding more fields to the data class. How should the remember function looks like? do I have to pass all arguments to `remember(...)` or just text styles because margins won't be recalculated?

Comment: @iknow I'm trying to pass all arguments just in case I'll change my mind in future and decide to make them dynamic, but if you're 100% sure you can skip them. Compose will calculate hash to determine difference, it's not a heavy operation especially for something like `dp`.

Comment: And what happens when my data class style only has `dp`  fields? Do I still have to use `remember` when passing this class to Composable? If not my data class will be created in every recomposition?

Comment: @iknow I think with just storing some constants it's not necessary, but I also don't see anything wrong with it. You can call `remember` even without keys.

Comment: One more question.  Can I use list of `TextStyles` in `remember` function? E.g. `val styles = listOf(textStyle1, textStyle2)` -> `remember(styles) { }`

Comment: @iknow sure, you can pass any value, which `hashCode` you expect to be changed. And you can pass them without a list if you need, just `remember(style1, style2)`

Comment: Helped me a lot. Tanks!